# Redirect GPU output in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, gpu

I'd like to redirect Windows Phone GPU to output other than screen (basically game rendering in real time) to a TV via DLNA or something similar. Something like dual monitor and that the other screen is a TV on a local network.
My searches came up with nothing useful.

Is there any kind of support for this in C#/JS/C++?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! This question appears to be off-topic because this site is for programming related questions, however you may find better help for your issue over at [Windows Phone Stack Exchange](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hi, questions is programming related, I edited the question. I'd like to achieve this result from my app.

Answer (score 0):

It's directly supported by the OS on suitable devices. See [this help page](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/connectivity/project-my-phone-screen).

Comment: Hi! I'm aware of this feature, but it's no what I'm looking for. I'm searching for something similar as "dual monitor", stream something via network to TV and have other content on your phone's display.